# java's closest python-generator implementation

Tags: java, python, generator

So I tried to implement a simple generator.

In Python, if I wanted to write a generator, I'd do something like this:

```
def a_generator():
    yield 1
    # paused, do some logic next call
    yield 'DONE'
```

And I made a generator class in Java

```
public abstract class Generator implements Iterable<Object> {

    private ArrayList<Object> yields = new ArrayList<>();

    public Generator() {
        run();
    }

    public void yield(Object element) {
        yields.add(element);
    }

    public Object next() {
        return yields.remove(0);
    }

    public abstract void run();

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return yields.iterator();
    }
}
```

it can yield any type of data, not just one

So now I can use it like this:

```
Generator gen = new Generator() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        yield(1);
        yield("DONE");
    }
}
```

and I can use enhanced forloop or calling next for one result at a time

BUT here's the issue: If I do something like this (if I have to pause code execution)

```
Generator generator = new Generator() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(3);
        yield(1);
        yield("DONE");
        System.out.println(2);
    }  
};
```

it would print:
    3
    2
    1
    "DONE"

So is it possible to implement "paused code execution"???

Comment: Well, yes with a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html); but you should really look at the Java 8+ [generators](https://thecannycoder.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/generators/).

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain how I would use "Future"?

Comment: The same way you would use a "promise" in python, see also [futures and promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but you can't expect Java to work like Python. It doesn't.

Comment: Oh okay, I finally understand now, thanks